# Function does not execute on razor page when called from javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, razor, razor-pages

I have been trying to call my function in the 'onsubmit' part of my form however, whenever I execute my application the alert is not appearing when searching an empty string.

When the function is written in the razor page itself (using script tags), it works fine. It seems like if I separate this function in its own javascript file, it does not want to work.

Razor Page Code:

[MainHomePage Razor Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jV1w.png)

My Javascript file:

```
function CheckForBlank() {
if (!document.getElementById("searchInput").value.trim().length) {
    alert("Please enter a card name.");
    return false;
}}
```

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure the javascript file is getting loaded? path and all are correct.. right?

Comment: It possibly could be the issue however, all I did was create a javascript file in my solution and link it the normal way. Is there a way to confirm it is loaded (It's my first time building a web application in asp.net)

Comment: When you check the page source from the browser, You can see whether is loaded or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found my issue and can sort it on my own now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to put the name of the function
It will work..

```html
<form method="post" onsubmit="CheckForBlank">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Try event.preventDefault() in if block of your function

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, sadly, this also did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
@section scripts{
<scipt>
function CheckForBlank() {
if (!document.getElementById("searchInput").value.trim().length) {
    alert("Please enter a card name.");
    return false;
}}
</script>
}
```

Comment: try to use like this by adding section scripts

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.